# VS solution keeps trying to connect to old TFS server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I just downloaded a solution from a TFS server [tfsserver2].

The solution was originally developed and uploaded to [tfsserver]

[tfsserver] crashed.  So this solution was then uploaded to tfsserver2.

I'm not the original developer, so I'm not sure how everything was setup.  When I try to edit this solution, it keeps trying to connect to [tfsserver] even though I got the solution from [tfsserver2].

I tried looking for references (ctrl+shift+f) to tfsserver, but I couldn't find anything.

I tried clearing the Visual Studio cache.

Any suggestions on how this solution even knows about a server that hasn't existed for years?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out your solution file & open it with an editor.
 You shoud find an entry like:`SccTeamFoundationServer =[tfsserver]`.
 Changing it to your new TFS should do the trick.
You could also do this with "File" > "Source Control" > "Change Source Control..."

---

Since we 're talking about VS2010, the SLN file follows the Format Version 11.00 of MS VStudio Solution File.
Within the `Global` part of it, source control information is kept as a `GlobalSection`.
For SCM Perforce this is headed as `GlobalSection(SourceCodeControl) = preSolution`, for TFS it's headed as `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution`.
You mention that when you select "Change Source Control" nothing happens. So, I would check out the SLN file, remove this section in a text editor, save & then load the solution in the IDE. It should then be possible to get where you 're headed, simply by right-clicking on the solution in Solution Explorer and selecting "Add Solution to Source Control...".

Comment: I'm unable to find the entry 'SccTeamFoundationServer'.  And when I click "Change Source Control", nothing happens.  Odd.

Comment: I checked out the solution file, and a different web file was being referenced.  I edited the reference, fixed some IIS paths and then it worked.  It's still unclear how the solution knew about [tfsserver] since I didn't find that name anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this link: http://computermutt.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/changing-url-of-team-foundation-server-2010-projects/

I commented on your question about checking the .sln and/or .vbproj/.csproj files, but I don't use TFS myself, so I'm not sure. Checking the internet learns that your .sln file should include something like:

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 2
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {xxxxx}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = http://some-other-guys-tfs-server/
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    SccProjectUniqueName1 = xxDemo\\xxDemo.csproj
    SccProjectName1 = xxDemo
    SccLocalPath1 = xxDemo
EndGlobalSection
```

I found the above here: [How can I completely remove TFS Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but wanted to share my solution.

1. Open C:\Documents and Settings[USER]\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\2.0\Cache folder\LocationServerMap.xml
2. Remove any ServerMapping entries you dont want

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <LocationServerMappings>
     <ServerMapping location="http://oldserver:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/LocationService.asmx" guid="..." />
     <ServerMapping location="http://oldserver:8080/tfs/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx" guid="..." />
     <ServerMapping location="http://oldserver:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx" guid="..." />
    </LocationServerMappings>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

TFS caches this information locally. Use the command line utility `tf`. Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt and type `tf` for available commands. In your cases, useful commands would be `workfold`, `workspace`, and `workspaces`.