# Remove project from TFS Source Control when Collection/Team Project don't exist

Tags: tfs

I have a Visual Studio Solution (2010) containing code projects that were under source control in Team Foundation Server 2010. That collection/project no longer exists, but the code was not removed from the collection. The collection and project have been created over again exactly as it was the first time. When I open the solution in VS, it tells me that it can find my project, it is offline, and asks if I would like to go online. I click yes, but then it errors and says it can not find the workspace. All my files are read only. I assume this is because of the source control and, since it's not hooked up, I can't check them out (remove the read only).

How do I purge the solution of the old and hook everything back up again, short of recreating all the code solutions over again?

**EDIT**

To clarify:
Collection refers to TFS Collection

Project refers to TFS Team Project

Solution refers to VS Code Solution

The problem is the code solutions are still associated with the team project, which doesn't exist. When I open it, I get the message "This solution is offline, but its associated TFS server is available. Would you like to go online with this solution after it has loaded?" Yes "Unable to determine the workspace for this solution"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I completely remove TFS Bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings)

Comment: I always try to check for that as much as I can before asking. I skimmed over the post. Seems like some overlap of solutions for a different problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you have loaded the projects, enable the Source Control - Team Foundation Server tool bar, click the "Change Source Control" button (only one enabled) and it asks you if you wish to permanently remove the association with source control.

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you. I tried this out on one of my solutions. Looked promising, but then I got a billion errors. Had to restart the server and now everything seems to be working fine.