# TFS - Remove Project Binding Externally Without VS 2010 Change Source Control Functionality

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a project which has been taken from TFS via GetLatest, I have read only access and thus am able to get the Latest code. Now I don't have checkout access for the project and thus I want this project to be disconnected, and I can modify some files.

I am trying to do it via Visual Studio 2010 --> File --> Source Control --> Change Source Control but there also, its giving error of no access to do that. Project Files are showing the lock icon against them which shows they are connected to TFS in read only mode.

While using SVN, I used to take the approach of deleting .SVN folders created (by searching .svn folders and deleting them all). Is there any similar approach applicable in TFS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to do it via the following:

1. Remove all files of type "Visual Studio Source Control Project Metadata File"
2. Edit Solution and Project Files and remove some TFS related stuff:

   In Solution File remove the section

   ```
   GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
      SccNumberOfProjects = 
      SccEnterpriseProvider = 
      SccTeamFoundationServer = 
      SccProjectUniqueName0 = 
      SccProjectName0 = 
      SccAuxPath0 = 
      SccLocalPath0 = 
      SccProvider0 = 
   EndGlobalSection
   ```

In Project File, I removed some entries:

```
<SccProjectName></SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath></SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath></SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider></SccProvider>
```

Hope it works for other too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use this tool to unbind: http://github.com/ralbu/UnbindTFS
It has the option to ignore folders which is helpful if you have a git repository

Answer (score 0):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/359145/127434

"File -> Source Control -> Change Source Control and then unbind and/or disconnect all projects and the solution."