# Missing: Add solution to source control

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have successfully installed and connected to my Team Foundation 2012 server. But I am unable to add my solution to it, Im missing it when I right click on the solution, see image below.

[image: Missing Add solution to source control]

If I try to create a new solution, I can add it to my source control.

Long time ago, I had the code on a Team Foundation server 2010, but when the trial ended I had to stop using that source control. Not sure if that has something to do with this tho.

Comment: Have you installed Team Explorer, and connected with it to your TFS server?

Comment: Yes, I can see the Team Explorer tab, and Ive created a Team Project from there.

Comment: And you are connected to TFS? That is, in Team Explorer, is the node of your TFS server open (so you can see a list of all Team Projects in it, and a "My Favorites" folder)? If not, you are not connected to your TFS server. You need this in order to be able to add an open solution to source control.

Comment: I have the same problem with VS 2012 SP 3, and the latest GIT install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Workspaces...

There I had to Edit my workspace and define a local local folder and a soruce control folder.

Right click on solution and click on Go online, then I was able to Add solution to Source control.

Comment: I cant find File > Source Control!

Comment: Check this if you can't find it http://stackoverflow.com/a/6137843/4795214

Answer (score 19):

This happen when the project had already a previous binding. Just do:

**File->Source Control->Advanced->Change Source Control**

You should see your project with Invalid Binding.

Do **Unbind** of the project, now you'll see again the "Add Project To Source Control"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

After creating a project in TFS server and connecting to it by using Team Explorer in visual studio, I followed below steps:

1. I closed VS and opened the .sln file in notepad and deleted below section.

   GlobalSection(SubversionScc) = preSolution
   Svn-Managed = True
   Manager = AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio
   EndGlobalSection
2. I opened .sln file in VS, selected 'Visual Studio Team Foundation Server' in Tools --> Options --> Source Control page.when I right clicked on solution file 'Add to Source Control' was there.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem.

I found I got two projects in my solution, one was under source control, the other one was not. What worked for me was to undo the project which was already under source control. After I undo all changes, I finally found the "source control" option when I right clicked the solution.

Answer (score 1):

- My `File menu -> Add to source control` option was missing in VS 2013. After opening the `Team explorer` tab (beside the`solution explorer` tab), It appeared again.
- Also make sure you have selected the correct plugin: `Tools -> Options -> Source control -> plugin-selection -> select Git`

Answer (score -3):

if your Datatable header responsive issue then use it

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
    $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
       .columns.adjust()
       .responsive.recalc();
 });
```