# Do csproj files in Git need xml tags SccProjectName, SccLocalPath, SccAuxPath, SccProvider with SAK values

Tags: git, visual-studio, csproj

I recently moved a solution from TFS to Git.

The CSPROJ used to have these lines:

```
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
```

Sometimes Visual Studio now removes them.

I believe that they tell the csproj file to go to the sln file to find out the source control bindings (SAK - Should Already Know). Git doesn't have any bindings in the sln file that I am aware of, so I should be able to remove them.

```
<SccProjectName>
</SccProjectName>
<SccLocalPath>
</SccLocalPath>
<SccAuxPath>
</SccAuxPath>
<SccProvider>
</SccProvider>
```

Can someone confirm that I can I safely remove them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can remove it, that's of no use in git.

That's information added when you're using TFVC version control. When you're using Git, these information are no more used.

Comment: I found this answer on Google... it would help next time, to explain what the tags ARE for, in order for the user to make an informed decision on whether or not they are needed.

Comment: You can also glean some info about how they used to be used [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467994).