# Visual Studio 2019 wants to use Git instead of TFS and also wants to use Azure DevOps server instead of TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, tfvc

Our Visual Studio 2019 is using Git when we want it to use our TFS 2018 server.
Also our VS wants to connect to an Azure DevOps server instead of TFS.

We do not want to use Git as our default.
Nor an Azure DevOps server.

How do we change these settings in Visual Studio 2019?

This is currently causing some errors when attempting to deploy our project.

Comment: Tools > Options > Source Control. That said, why are you wanting to use TFS today? I _hope_ you're transitioning to git sooner rather than later...

Answer (score 0):

It seemed the project you opened in VS is under Git version control. You could try to close VS, navigate to the project folder, and delete the `.git*` files and folder:

- Remove the *hidden* `.git` folder
- Removed the `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore` files

Comment: Also check the `.csproj` file for source-control MSBuild properties as well, such as `<SccProvider>`, and the `*.sln` file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467994/why-missing-sccprojectname-in-project-file-cause-the-project-file-is-not-boun