# Visual studio 2013 team project has been deleted

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

After adding a new web solution to source control in vs 2013 and check in for the first time, I get this error:

```
TF402484: The "PROJECTNAME" team project has been deleted. 
Undo any pending changes to that project or branches from 
that project in your local workspace. Then retry the operation.
```

If i try to choose "Undo any pending changes" it tell me that there are no pending changes. Now I cant "get latest" or "check in" any other solutions and I get the same error. The source control explorer doesnt show anything other than "working..." and I get the same error. The projects is not vissible to others in the team.

Anyone else experience something like this? I have remove the project from the workspace. Can I remove the project from VS 2013 in any other way?

Comment: Sounds like a file that is part of your checkin is crossing the team project boundary..

Answer (score 51):

I just experienced this as my colleague deleted projects in TFS where I have connection to those projects. The way i solved it:

In Team Explorer, click to Pending Changes. you will see there are four section in it which is Comment, Related Work Items, Included Changes and Excluded Changes. Look at Excluded Changes section if there are any files which belong to deleted folder. If yes, right click at the file name and choose Undo.

Comment: I continued to get the message even after undoing pending changes. I also had to delete the workspace that had a mapping to the deleted project to finally get rid of the error.

Comment: I dont have anything inside Excluded Changes still getting the msg

Answer (score 11):

This is how I solved it:

- Go to Team Explorer.
- In the left you will find "Folders".
- Right click on "DefaultCollection" (or the collection the project you deleted -used to be in) and choose "Undo Pending Changes".
- Choose the files of the project you have deleted.
- Confirm the Undo changes.

Comment: This solution isn't an option for me, as I never get to a point where the folders load. Visual Studio just says "Working" and then presents me with a TF402484 error a few times.

Answer (score 9):

The best thing to do is to click on the Pending Changes box (shown below) on the Team Explorer menu of Visual Studio. Then scroll down to the perpetrator project and undo the changes by right click => Undo pending changes (as detailed above).

This is better because Visual Studio won't even give you the opportunity to do anything as the error message will keep popping up.

Here is a screenshot of the button that you need to click in order to get to the Problematic project and undo its pending changes:

[image]

Comment: When I undo the changes, I am able to add solution to the new TFS folder but after that this message with old project allways appears, how the .... can I FOREVER force visual studio to forgot that project ? Where the information about folder x tfs mapping is stored ?

Comment: @Muflix To guarantee that a Project is completely unbound from TFS please follow the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings  by Matt Frear. Also, I'd add that you delete (from all assemblies within your solution directory) all of the TFS files; these usually have extensions of: .vspscc and .vssscc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to arise when you have a folder under your root TFS local workspace directory which is not part of a TFS project. Since this is not actually a TFS project, the path does not exist on the remote server and the above error is persistently shown until the pending change is "undone".

For example, in my case I had a git repo under my TFS local workspace that contained the source code for an open source project I was using.  Somehow TFS was trying to check in one of those files, and not surprisingly TFS could not find it on the remote server as it was just a local clone of a GitHub repository. After having the file re-added after several "undo pending changes". I copied the source code, deleted the file, and recreated it, finally free of the bonds of TFS.

It seems that the reason the file from the GitHub project got added to the TFS tracking system in the first place was because I added a file to the GitHub project from inside the TFS solution that referenced the GitHub project. This caused an automatic add to take place, triggering the issues described above.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to undo pending changes. Close Visual Studio. Then open the solution by double clicking on the .sln file rather than opening it from within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I try the following solution and it works well on my Pc:

- Go to: C:\Users\\Source\Workspaces;
- Delete the folder releted to the project deleted on the web.

Answer (score -1):

Open visual studio and go to team explorer. Then click the little plug icon to go to the "connect" screen. One there click the "connect to team projects" link at the top of the panel. This will give you a list of server and the projects that you have checked for your connection.

This the check mark for the project that no longer exists.

Answer (score -1):

Open solution in Visual Studio, right click solution name (in Solution Explorer) and select Source Control -> Undo Pending Changes...
Find the items that are linked to the deleted project and undo them.

Comment: This just duplicates several existing answers.