# Change Bindings on TFS project

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, tfs

I wanted to add a solution to a project, but accidentally added a solution to the wrong Team Project.

Before adding the project, I made a copy locally.  I then deleted the project in Source Explorer and ran a checkin.  This deleted the code from the local drive.

I then restore the code from the local copy.  Opened the solution and removed the bindings from the Change Source Control form.

The issue I have is every time I try to add the solution back to source control, it is automatically added to the first project.  Is there a way to pick the project you add a solution to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn’t completely remove TFS Bindings.

There is a tool to **remove Source Control Bindings** from Visual Studio Solutions and Projects from msdn: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2012/08/11/a-tool-to-remove-source-control-bindings-from-visual-studio-solutions-and-projects.aspx

More ways and more information for you reference:  [How can I completely remove TFS Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings)