# How do you delete an outstanding TFS team project root directory?

Tags: tfs

How do you delete an outstanding TFS team project root directory?

The team project, `MyProblemProject`, has been deleted from TFS, but my local file system still has the root directory.

If I delete my local directory, `C:\Dev\MyProblemProject`, Visual Studio flags the delete as a pending excluded change. But if I try and promote the delete change, I get the error ...

`TF101069: Unsupported pend change attempted on team project $/MyProblemProject. Use the Project Creation Wizard in Team Explorer to create a project or the Team Project deletion tool to delete one`

Tried using `tfsdeleteproject` but it gives a `TF200016 The project does not exist`

So how can I delete the local directory and not have Visual Studio see it as a delete change?

*... and why does VS still think the directory is in TFS, as I can't see the `MyProblemProject`?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible you didn't completely delete your project in TFS server. 
Then your local directory still have some source control bindings. This is why VS still detected the changes.

However, there is a workaround for this situation -- remove the bindings of your local mapping folder. [Change Bindings on TFS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33087053/change-bindings-on-tfs-project/33100241#33100241)

If it still doesn't work, sometimes, the binding info is cached. Try to delete TFS cache by going into default `C:\ {User Profile Folder}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache` and `VS cache` in `appdata` folder.

Moreover, we usually delete team project in TFS through below two ways:

- [Delete it in TFS Administration Console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff357756.aspx)
- Use tfs command

  ```
  TfsDeleteProject /collection:https://xxx.8080/tfs/DefaultCollection MyProject
  ```

Comment: I think I did the same steps you do, but the local directory was still "in TFS" ... ended up fixing it by recreating the team project with the same name, then do the TfsDeleteProject