# I am trying to change the source control binding for a project, it was previously bound to a folder in tfs but I want to bind it to another.

Tags: version-control, bind, unbind, tfs-2015, source-control-bindings

I have unbound the project and then hoped to re-bind it to a different directory within tfs but it only rebinds it to the same location and does not let me edit that location. I have deleted the suo file within the project and tried to add it to source control and it binds it to the initial directory as well.

I could just add it to source control and then 'move' it to the correct directory, but there should be a way to disconnect it and reconnect it in a different folder right? Or is moving it the only way to change this?

I have read quite a few threads and the options given (change source control, unbind, bind and change directory) do not work because when I click bind it will not let me edit the server name/server binding, it only rebinds it to the original bound location.
[change source control screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBfBs.png)

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t completely remove TFS Bindings.（Your method didn't work）

There is a tool to **remove Source Control Bindings** from Visual Studio Solutions and Projects from MSDN: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2012/08/11/a-tool-to-remove-source-control-bindings-from-visual-studio-solutions-and-projects.aspx

How to use the tool:

•Copy your solution to a new directory (because the tool does modify files)

•Run this command: VSUnbindSourceControl.exe (ex. d:\yourfolder)

More ways and more information for you reference: [How can I completely remove TFS Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings)

Answer (score 0):

First and Foremost please check if the Solutions and the projects are in sync with the TFS Paths

**Manually check every project having issue**

or Try the following steps

Navigate to File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control.

Select Invalid Projects with Status as invalid

Select Unbind

Repeat for all the other invalid projects (If any)

Select all the Invalid projects

Click in Bind

click on Refresh

Try loading solutions

**If the issue still persists do the following**
Navigate to

File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control

Select Invalid Projects with Status as invalid

Select Unbind

Repeat for all the other invalid projects (If any)

Go to Solution Explorer, Unload the project then Reload the project

Repeat to all the other invalid projects

try loading the solution

Should you still get errors for binding, it means the Project files are not 
having proper mapping for the project location and TFS locations

**Should you still get invalid status**

then try doing the following

Navigate to your project workspace

Delete the workspace

Rebind the workspace

Get latest

Try loading the solutions

**Good Luck**