# Adding a project to the TFS server

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, visual-studio-express

I have my project already added to the online TFS server of Visual Studio. Now I want to unbind the project from the online TFS server. I have already tried unbinding the Project from the advanced options of Source control.

When I try to add the project to the source control after unbinding, the server name of the TFS remains the online TFS server. How can i change the name of the TFS server?

I have tried most solutions given on SO and internet. But nothing could help me to change the name of the tfs server

Comment: If the solution is still sitting in a local folder which is mapped to the original TFS server then it will try and put it back there.  Map a folder to a workspace on the new server.  Copy across the unbound solution and try re-adding to source control.  It should pick up the new server.  We could hand edit the sln file but I suspect it's a workspace thing

Comment: I found the solution for my problem. but i do ot really know the exact steps I followed to add an answer. I added a new tfs server via the team explorer and got it all working. But I also deleted the account i had on online visual studio tfs. But even after deleting i was not able to change the server name; but through the team menu on the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

You didn’t completely remove TFS Bindings.

There is a tool to remove Source Control Bindings from Visual Studio Solutions and Projects from msdn: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2012/08/11/a-tool-to-remove-source-control-bindings-from-visual-studio-solutions-and-projects.aspx

More ways and more information for you reference: [How can I completely remove TFS Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings)

Moreover, If the online TFS mean Visual Studio Team Services(VSonline), to change your server name(server account), please refer this link [Change Visual Studio Team Services account owner](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/change-account-ownership-vs) from MSDN.