# VS2015 Change TFS Source Control Bindings from Command Line?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I need a way to add bindings to my VS2015 solution from the command line. In the GUI, the way this is done is File->Source Control->Advanced->Change Source Control. Then I would select the items that are not connected to my TFS server, hit OK, and Save All. The solution then has the items I want added to the bindings.

What I need is a way to do this same operation from the command line if possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can't change source control bindings through a TFS command simply.

However, as a workaroud you can delete the `.suo` next to the `.sln` file, and then opened the `.sln` file in Notepad and deleted this entire section:

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 2
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {xxxxx}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = http://some-other-guys-tfs-server/
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    SccProjectUniqueName1 = xxDemo\\xxDemo.csproj
    SccProjectName1 = xxDemo
    SccLocalPath1 = xxDemo
EndGlobalSection
```

Save the `.sln` in Notepad and then open in Visual Studio.

More details please refer *Matt Frear*'s answer in this question [How can I completely remove TFS Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings)

---

**Update**

No, you also can't do this through command Line to add bindings.

`TF.exe` are  version control commands. You may have to manually rebind it in VS.

> On the **File** menu, click **Source Control**, and then click
>   **Change Source Control**. In Change Source Control dialog box, click **Bind**.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking to delete bindings, I need to add them.

Comment: No, you also can't do this through command Line to add bindings. `TF.exe` are  version control commands. You may have to manually rebind it in VS. On the File menu, click Source Control, and then click Change Source Control.
In Change Source Control dialog box, click Bind.

Comment: +1 "On the File menu, click Source Control, and then click Change Source Control. In Change Source Control dialog box, click Bind."

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio to make changes to the source control bindings, it will change details found in the solution and project files.

If you take a snapshot of these files before making a binding change, make the binding change and then run a difference of the before and after files, that difference will show what changes were made by that process.

With information it should be possible to come up with a way to automate that change using a suitable command line tool.