# TFS not automatically adding new files

Tags: .net, tfs

I have a new Solution and TFS is not automatically adding new files or deleting ones when I delete.  Other solutions in the workspace automatically add/delete.  I have checked and the Workspace is Local.  The project does not end in .Lib.  I tried the "Add solution to Source Control" route and I receive a dialog stating the .sln is already under source control at the selected location.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did this error only occurs on your machine or everyone in your team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First double check if the newly added files are added in the Excluded section on the pending changes page.

If you are seeing the issue only on your machine then the TFS source control binding might be broken for the project.  Try to [unbind and rebind the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings) in source control.

Also give a try with [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/).