# Sharing violation While TFS Build Defintion Copies Files

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, msbuild

I am sometimes getting  Sharing Violation error while TFS Build definition starts copying files. Mostly DLL or Exe and With WinServices. Sometimes it works perfectly and sometimes gives this error.

2018-04-20T14:40:14.7193845Z Sharing violation
2018-04-20T14:40:14.7818767Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 4.
2018-04-20T14:40:14.7818767Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Artifacts

Answer (score 0):

There may be some problems in the build as projects copy themselves and their dependencies (other projects, references, NuGet packages, etc) into the same output folder.

> This error occurs because you have added files to source control **that
>   should not be in there**. Therefore it is downloaded from TFS and marked
>   as read only.

Take a look at this similar question: [Error VSP1737: File could not be opened due to sharing violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340348/error-vsp1737-file-could-not-be-opened-due-to-sharing-violation)

You could use a `.tfignore file`. You will have to manually remove all of the files that have already been added. How to please refer my reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36784750/5391065).

> Then check for *.dll and other binaries, including *.vsp files and
>   remove them from source control.
>
> There are two types of binaries:
>
> 1. **References** - these should be done using Nuget and never included in source control or added manually.
> 2. **output/generated** - No generated files should be added to source control.

How to use Nuget to manage dll, take a look at below tutorials:

- [NuGet is now fully integrated into MSBuild](https://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html)
- [Get started with NuGet Package Management in VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/get-started-nuget?view=vsts)