# Visual Studio 2015 - TFS source code binding issue

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, version-control

I'm using tfs with VS 2015 for a project. I have made some changes to the project locally outside of visual studio and I want to check the changes back into the version on tfs.

However when I open the project in Visual Studio I get the following error message:

```
The solution appears to be under source control, but it's binding 
information cannot be found. Becuase it is not possible to recover this 
missing informtion automatically, the projects whose binding are missing 
will be treated as not under source control.
```

when I open the project by connecting to the server using Team Explorer and re-opening the solution, it doesn't detect the changes that I've made locally.

How do I open the project in Visual Studio and bind it back the version on tfs so that I can check i n the changes I made outside of Visual Studio?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can't seem to figure out. I've had to create a new tfs project and add the local version to it.

Comment: Are you using a server or local workspace?

Comment: What's the behavior if you right click on the solution and select add solution to source control?

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter such the binding issues next time, a feasible solution should be unbinding/ rebinding the files in TFS source control

> **File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control** and then **unbind** and/or disconnect all projects and the solution.
>
> This should remove all bindings from the solution and project files.
>   (After this you could also switch the SCC provider in Tools -> Options ->
>   Source Control -> Plug-in Selection).

More ways (such as using this tool- [CleanProject](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RonJacobs.CleanProject-CleansVisualStudioSolutionsForUploadi)) please refer this question: [How can I completely remove TFS Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings)