# Unable to get latest from TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I have my source code in TFS.

The issue is that `when i try to get the latest files from the TFS, I am made to wait for 5 minutes for connecting to server` to get. and then it says timed out! Then i will have to connect to the TFS again.

Still not able to get the code!
I had `tried mapping it to a different folder` but even that failed.

I am using `Visual Studio 2012 Express for web`.

I have already `tried clearing all the local data, cache` and all that kind o stuff. I even `tried resetting the user data`.

Also `tried logging in with another account` to check weather if it was an issue with my Hotmail account(it's not. because i am not able to get it even with another Id).

Nothing helped!

---

**Issue Fixed!**

Here are the steps i did to fix it.
Since **clearing all files may reset all your settings on visual studio**, this should be the last possible option to do.

> 1. Just did a repair on the VS 2012,
> 2. cleared everything from
>      `C:\Users\(Username)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache`
> 3. Clear everything from
>      `C:\Users\(Username)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio`
> 4. Clear everything from
>      `C:\Users\(Username)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon`

---

**But here is another issue.**

I had added a file by mistake to a different repo. I have deleted that from the server(Online). but `the deleted project file is still shown in my source explorer in VS` with a plus sign! How do i remove those?

if anyone have any idea, please help! Thanks a lot..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your project file still have some source control bindings. So that file can be detect as new add file in source control explorer. You need to remove source control bindings.

There is a tool to **remove Source Control Bindings** from Visual Studio Solutions and Projects from msdn:  [Remove Source Control Bindings from Visual Studio Solutions and Projects](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saveenr/2012/08/11/a-tool-to-remove-source-control-bindings-from-visual-studio-solutions-and-projects/) Detail steps as below:

Delete the `.suo` next to the `.sln` file, and then opened the `.sln` file in Notepad and deleted this entire section:

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 2
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {xxxxx}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = http://some-other-guys-tfs-server/
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    SccProjectUniqueName1 = xxDemo\\xxDemo.csproj
    SccProjectName1 = xxDemo
    SccLocalPath1 = xxDemo
EndGlobalSection
```

Save the `.sln` in Notepad and then open in Visual Studio.

More ways and more information for you reference:  [How can I completely remove TFS Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings)

Comment: i am connected to my TFS server and i can't disconnect because i have lot code that is not in sync. everything is fine except for some extra folders in the TFS root. i have deleted them from the Online server. but they still appear in my local.

Comment: Which workspace are you using server workspace or local workspace? If you are using local workspace, you can directly delete those extra folders in local. And also double check the files in pending changes ? If  you could see the deleted server files in pending changes, you may have to check in to accomplish the delete operation.

Comment: I am using a local workspace...
i dont see any delete option! :(

Comment: Could you add a related screenshot. I'm not sure if I got your point. Did you mean there are some folders  in local workspace on your dev machine even though there have been deleted in TFS server. Then you could directly delete those folders in local on your dev machine. Just like delete files in windows.

Comment: it was a terrible mistake... it was pending yet! The whole file! so just an undo pending changes did the trick! I thought it was some stupid link with the TFS cache where the deleted folder from the server is appearing on the source control explorer. since i had added that from the TFS itself, it was still there as a pending change! Misleading names....... :D

Answer (score 1):

Solution for the second question!

It was a misunderstanding of the pending Change.

I had deleted the folder from the server but the file names still appeared on the TFS source explorer on VS.

It was just because VS did recognize it as a pending change to be checked in even-though it wasn't one!

So just an `undo pending changes`did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

In TFS server have you set all privileges (access) for your account. If not then add Administrative access for your account on TFS.