# Vs 2015 TFS can't checkin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs

When checkin my pending changes VS got the errror:

```
%error="500004";%:(null): database update failure - error %error="(null)";% executing (null) statement for (null)`
```

[image]

I have no idea about this.Please give me a hand,thanks!

Comment: Any update on this error, did you fix it?

Comment: Pre Checkin is OK, But this time is not working now.

Comment: Usually this kind of issue is related to cache. You could close VS, clear the cache follow the link in my answer , reopen VS, try the check in operation again. If the error still exist, back up/move your files in local, delete the old workspace , recreate a workspace, which should do the trick.

Comment: Hi huoxudong125, any update on this issue, did my reply helped to figure out it ?

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT I reinstall the vs2015 before you replied

Comment: Did the issue fixed? If  still exists even after reinstall VS, then you could try to back up local files including pending changes, delete the old local workspace, recreated a new workspace, get files from server, add changes, finally check in the changes. Another way please refer my update reply.

Comment: I don't clear the old workspace, reopen it with Vs2015(reinstalled) I can check in. BTW Where the error is thrown, or which component may cause the error.@Patrick-MSFT

Comment: Thank you for your feedback huoxudong125. According to the error info in screenshot and your description `Pre Checkin is OK, But this time is not working now.` this generic a **database update error**  which could occur for a wide range of reasons  such as disk issues or cache issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/). Make sure you have backed up the changes first.

---

**Update**

If above is not working, then you could try to backup local files including pending changes, delete the old workspace, recreated a new workspace, get files from server, add changes, finally check in the files.

Another way is unbind and rebind TFS source control binding of that special file, detail steps please refer this link: [How can I completely remove TFS Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings)