# Getting a "vspscc could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it" error

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Today, while trying to publish an app so I could test it, I suddenly got this error message:

> The item
>   D:\ScratchSrc\TryNewReportViewer2017\TryNewReportViewer2017\TryNewReportViewer2017.csproj.vspscc
>   could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to
>   access it.

That's a mystery to me, as I've never gotten this before and I was working with this app just last week. Publishing it, too.

I've looked for the .vspscc file. Found it exactly where it said it should be. So, the alternative is that I don't have permissions to it. I don't understand why I shouldn't have permissions to a file on my machine that I created, but whatever. So, how do I get permissions to my own file?

I'm working with VS 2017, TFS 2015 on premise.

Comment: Possibly related issue on GitHub -- https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1801

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another reason for this problem is, that the vspscc file is not checked in.
Just do a "Compare" on the project folder to see, if it's missing.

Answer (score 14):

This issue may due to the wrong source control binding for that specific `xx.vspscc` file.

Double **check your source control bindings** for that file in TFS. You could also try to [unbind and rebind the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings).

Then delete the file in local(back up local changes first) and get latest version from TFS. Finally do the publish again.

If above solution is still not working, try to delete local workspace and create a new one, get latest version of the file, modify the file with local changes (if you have) in your backup , check in the file, then do the publish .

Comment: But why would it suddenly be an issue? How would the source control binding change?

Comment: @jbyrd It's hard to determine the root cause. `.vspscc` is a Source Code Control (SCC) file for projects created with Microsoft Visual Studio; contains metadata used for tracking revisions of Visual Studio software development projects; includes information such as the version number, file path, and the number of nested projects. If this file got some issue, this may related to source control binding. Why source control binding change , may be related to local workspace issue, file changed , merge issue and so on.

Comment: The file is not in the source control, I've deleted the project folder and also the source bindings, did the clean get and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 2):

If the csproj.vspscc is missing you can create a new one by removing the project in visual studio and adding it back

Answer (score 1):

I was able to 'fix' the problem by going to the source control explorer, selecting the smproj file (which was checked out for editing), and checked it in by itself. Then, I checked in the Model.bim. Was able to do both of these things without getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried all the usual things, deleting the entire solution directory, getting it from TFS again but nothing worked.

Noticed the version of Visual Studio 2019 was a few months old so upgraded to the latest. That fixed it!