# Visual Studio 2017 on Team Explorer tab missing Builds work Items Reports

Tags: build, visual-studio-2017

I have Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017 on my machine. I cannot see Builds under Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2017. I can see it in Visual Studio 2015. I was connected to the same collection and project and had the same credentials.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you are connected to team foundation server.

Go to Source Control Explorer and try opening the solution again after connecting to TFS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the situation is very likely you are opening a local project in VS2017.

Suggest you double check your project source control binding. You could try to unbind and rebind it. How to do this please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359145/5391065).

You could also connect some other projects and collections in VS2017 to narrow down if the issue is only with that specific project.

Comment: I cannot Builds list, where I can see it in VS 2015. And I don't have option to add bindings

Comment: @sukanya Could you add a related screenshot in your update question. If you don't have option to add bindings, afraid the project is not in source control. One simple workaround, you could back up your local changes first, deleted your local workspace, create a new one and get latest version of the project from TFS, finally open the project in VS, the issue should go away.

Comment: @sukanya Suggest you also try to [clear TFS and VS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) cache on your develop machine and  [reset your VS Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms247075(v=vs.100).aspx) which may do the trick, then open your project in VS again to see if the missing Builds work items reports come back.

Comment: I just opened solution for particular project then I was able to see all the builds of that project