# TFS Source Control Binding

Tags: visual-studio-2017, tfs-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I was on windows 7 with Visual Studio 2017 with data tools held in tfs.  I have a reporting solution that runs great.  Today I installed the exact same thing on a windows 10 machine and first thing it did was asked to upgrade the solution and now every time I open the solution it asks if I want to use source control binding.  Happening on a co-workers machine also.  Anyone have any idea what is happening?

The tfs server version is 2015

Comment: Did this issue only occurs on the specific  reporting solution?

Answer (score 1):

Open up your solution (.sln) file in notepad. Double check if there are the section that has references to Scc like below

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 1
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = http://yourtfs:8080/tfs/defaultcollection
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    SccProjectUniqueName1 = WebApplication\\WebApplication.csproj
    SccProjectName1 = WebApplication
    SccLocalPath1 = WebApplication
EndGlobalSection
```

Also try to unbind the specific solution and rebind it. How to do this please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359145/5391065).

Finally [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/), then try to open the solution again see if  issue is gone.

Comment: I wish there was a way to right click on your solution that is open, and right click it and have an option to "Remove Solution From SourceControl" when source control is detected, online or offline.

Answer (score 0):

That's a known issue for the SSDT 17.3 for Vsual Studio 2015 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/changelog-for-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt#ssdt-173-for-visual-studio-2015
Maybe someone is using that version and causing an issue

Comment: So basically its a waiting game until they fix the issue?!

Comment: Not sure, it may not be the issue, but it does really sound like the same thing. I'd suggest opening/searching on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html too