# TF206016: cannot check code into TFS Online

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

When I attempt to check code into TFS Online, I get the following response in VS 2015:

> TF206016: Check-in operation was stopped because after saving all your
>   open files, the system pended changes to some additional files. Review
>   your pending changes, make sure all related changes are selected, and
>   then perform the check-in operation again.

The exact process is:

1. Hit check in button
2. Get prompted to save project file
3. Hit Yes to save project file
4. See project file appear then disappear in Included Changes list
5. Get above message

If I click not to save the project file, I get told that there are unsaved modified files.

I've closed and reopened Visual Studio. I've rebooted. I've never seen this in any other projects. (Even today, in between instances of this, I successfully checked in code for another project.) I also change my mapping so I'm in a completely different file system path than I was originally.

The one (other) weird thing I see is that I have a .vbproj.vspscc file in the Included changes list. Excluding that file from the check-in list makes no difference, though.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this issue occur on other clients? You can try checing this on another machie, also check if the check in works with VS 2017.

Comment: Now that Thanksgiving is passed, I finally was able to get someone else to try it. He was able to modify a file and check it in successfully. I got latest and then was able to check in my changes. I tested later and was unable to check in again, but after I did a get latest again, I was able to check in, even though nothing had changed on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Based on the comments below, **Get latest version from TFS** solved the issue.

Sounds like changed or missed something in your local workspace. When get latest the sources are overrided. So everything works. Whatever it's solved, you can also try to create a new workspace or remap the existhing workspace next time.

---

According to the error message, firstly you need to check if **all related changes are selected**.

Besides, this issue may due to the wrong source control binding for that specific `xx.vspscc` file.

> Team Foundation uses these to store lists of files that have been
>   excluded from source control.  We leveraged some of the existing SCC
>   integration layer in Visual Studio to integrate Team Foundation, and
>   these files were one of the carryovers.  I'll have to check into what
>   the logic was in breaking out these SCC settings into separate files
>   as opposed to putting them in the solution and project files' SCC
>   sections.
>
> ***Source link*** : [Why do you need the .vspscc and .vssscc files](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9920911d-1a7e-4ada-90cd-b1b910586cf4/why-do-you-need-the-vspscc-and-vssscc-files?forum=tfsgeneral)

Please check if the `.vbproj.vspscc` is in source control. See if it existing in TFS remote repo (Code hub). If it existing, just try below things:

Double **check your source control bindings** for that file in TFS. You could also try to [unbind and rebind the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings).

Then delete the file in local(back up local changes first) and get latest version from TFS. Finally do the Check in again.

If that still not work, just try to ignore the reated files by creating [`.tfignore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-files-server#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control) or [`.gitignore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/tutorial/ignore-files?tabs=visual-studio#use-gitignore-to-prevent-tracking-of-files) file.

Comment: I really don't think it's the vspcc file that's the issue. The key seems to be whatever is modifying the vbproj file when I hit the check in button, but I have no idea what that is.

Comment: @PaulSmithJr As you said "`The one (other) weird thing I see is that I have a .vbproj.vspscc file in the Included changes list.` " Whatever have you tried the suggestions mentioned in above answer?  The `vbproj` file of course will be changed when you change something in the project. Just make sure you have saved the changes before check in. And all the related files are selected and in source control.

Comment: Now that Thanksgiving is passed, I finally was able to get someone else to try it. He was able to modify a file and check it in successfully. I got latest and then was able to check in my changes. I tested later and was unable to check in again, but after I did a get latest again, I was able to check in, even though nothing had changed on the server.