# Repository info in Visual Studio Solution

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfvc

I copied and pasted an existing solution with multiple projects into a new folder. The original solution is bound to a repository on VSTS.

I was careful to copy only the actual project files I created along with the `sln` file. When I opened the new version, I got the following messages.

[image]

[image]
In the `sln` file, I don't see any information about the repo. Where is the repo information stored? What file do I need to edit to remove all references to a repository?

P.S. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 on my computer and on VSTS, I'm using TFVC for version control.

Update:
When I go to File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control, I see no bindings. See image below.
[image]

When I click the "Team Explorer", I get the following message.
[image]

I don't think I have any workspaces configured. See below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual way:

1. Remove TeamFoundationversionControl section from sln file (open it through Notepad)

For example:

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
        SccNumberOfProjects = 4
        SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
        SccTeamFoundationServer = https://XXX.visualstudio.com/
        SccLocalPath0 = .
        SccProjectUniqueName1 = ClassLibraryStandard20\\ClassLibraryStandard20.csproj
        SccProjectName1 = ClassLibraryStandard20
        SccLocalPath1 = ClassLibraryStandard20
        SccProjectUniqueName2 = ConsoleAppwithStandard\\ConsoleAppwithStandard.csproj
        SccProjectName2 = ConsoleAppwithStandard
        SccLocalPath2 = ConsoleAppwithStandard
        SccProjectUniqueName3 = WebApplication1\\WebApplication1.csproj
        SccProjectName3 = WebApplication1
        SccLocalPath3 = WebApplication1
    EndGlobalSection
```

2. Delete .vs folder
3. Delete vspscc files (e.g. {project name}.csproj.vspscc, same folder level of project file)
4. Remove Scc… sections from each project files

For example:

```
<SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
```

Comment: I was pretty sure this would work but I'm still getting the warning. I did all 4 items you mentioned in your answer. Also when I go into File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control, I see no bindings -- see the image I uploaded to original post. Yet, when I open up the project, I'm still getting the warning that the solution is bound to source control. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sam Try to copy the solution folder to other path (do not in any workspaces) and try again.

Comment: Do you mean, I should make a fresh new copy of the original code from the folder that's under source control, THEN follow your 4 steps?

Comment: @Sam No, it doesn't affect anything, just make sure the files are not in any workspaces of VSTS,

Comment: Sorry but I'm clear about what you're saying. I posted new images in the original post. Looks like I don't have any workspaces configured. But I'm getting those messages.

Comment: It was my mistake. Looks like I skipped the section in the `sln` file completely. I now removed it and the messages disappeared. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This solution has worked perfect for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to unbind & rebind the projects/files from source control.

> File -> Source Control -> Advanced -> Change Source Control

[Remove Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings)

Unbind and/or disconnect all projects and the solution.It deletes/removes all bindings from the solution and project files. Next/Other step is to to bind source.

> Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug-in Selection

Comment: This is not working for me. See the image I uploaded under Update in original post. I see no bindings yet when I open the solution, I still get the warning.

Comment: @Sam - Try clear/remove local mapping in workspace and freshly do the local mapping.