# TFS: The command you are attempting cannot be completed because the file 'aaaaa.vdproj' is under source control

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I have a Visual installer project on TFS, recently I switched to TFS git but when I try to update version or any other update it say *the command you are attempting cannot be completed because the file is under source control*, I used to get the same problem on TFS and fixed with Check Out for Edit. How to Check Out for the edit on TFS git? I am using vs Enterprise 2017, Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't check out files in Git. That's not how Git works. You need to [unbind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings) the TFVC bindings for the solution.

Answer (score 8):

If you use GIT and can't "check out" try the following workaround, maybe it can help:

- Choose 'Open file in File explorer' in your context menu
- Open the project file in your favorite texteditor
- Make a dummy change (adding a space character in an empty spot is
  enough), Visual studio will prompt to reload the project and has explicity
  checked out the project file.

Comment: This is a good answer to use in VS2019 if you're using Git, but you've inherited an old project which has some kind of SourceSafe remnant in it

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with **Visual Studio 2019** and **TFS**.

I solved it by closing and opening Visual Studio...

Answer (score 0):

Open your .vdproj file in Team Explorer window => Source Control Explorer.
Right click on .vdproj and click "Check Out for Edit" solves the problem.