# Communication with TFS from client project

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have client project (angular) that hosted on tfs.
In Solution explorer in Visual Studio window I don't see any indication showing connection to tfs.

Is there a way to see an indication of the tfs in such a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the project folder to a new project template: Blank Azure Node.js Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

For different source control, there is different indication.

If you are using **TFVC**. In the front of your project, there should be a lock icon which indicate the project file already in TFS Server.

[image]

If you are using **Git**. You could find this info in the status bar.

[image]

> - `2` shows the number of unpublished commits in your local branch.    Selecting this opens the Synchronization view in Team Explorer.
> - `3` shows the number of uncommitted file changes. Selecting this opens    the Changes view in Team Explorer.
> - `FabrikamFiberWeb` shows the current Git repo. Selecting this opens the    Connect view in Team Explorer.
> - `master` shows your current Git branch. Selecting this displays a    branch picker to quickly switch between Git branches or create new
>     branches.

**Note:** 
If you don't see any icons such as 2 or 3, ensure that you have a project open that is part of a Git repo. If your project is brand new or not yet added to a repo, you can add it to one by selecting [image] on the status bar, or by right-clicking your solution in Solution Explorer and choosing **Add Solution to Source Control**.

More details about how to use Visual Studio and Azure DevOps Git Repo please refer this official tutorial--[Share your code with Visual Studio 2017 and Azure Repos Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-vs-2017?view=azure-devops).

Comment: What you're saying is obvious, and that's my problem, I see the project in TFS, but not see any indication on files in solution explorer window.

Comment: @Ruthi Are you using Git or TFVC? For Git, it's an expected behavior.

Comment: I use TFVC, Can you help me?

Comment: @Ruthi Did you mean you could not able to see the lock icon in your solution explorer? If there is not a lock icon. Sounds like your source control binding is not correct. Suggest you **unbind and rebind** your source control binding for your project and solution. How to please refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358951/how-can-i-completely-remove-tfs-bindings  If this stilding

Comment: Hi Ruthi, How about the issue, is there anything to update?Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Thank you, I dont have time to check it, I move to work on another project. I will check it as soon as possible.